# How to convert column values to column names in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table as follows:

```
Name     Subjects 
X         math 
Y         science
Z         english
```

I need a report in the following format:

```
  Name      math     science     english
    X         Y         N          N
    Y         N         Y          N
    Z         N         N          Y
```

How do I achieve this using a single select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'a common question, search for "PIVOT query" :-)

Assuming one Name can have multiple Subjects you need to use MAX/GROUP BY, otherwise simply remove the aggregation.

```
select
   Name,
   max(case when Subjects = 'math' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as Math,
   max(case when Subjects = 'science' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as Science,
   max(case when Subjects = 'english' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as English
from tab
group by Name
```